# Como eu insiro NA, ou desvio de dados faltantes, ao fazer Webscraping (rvest) de uma página em R?

Tags: html, css, r, variáveis, rvest

Estou baixando as tarifas de hotéis em Natal- RN pelo site Booking.com.

O código é programado para baixar de acordo com a data de check-in o nome do hotel (`nomes_i`), o nome do quarto (`quarto_i`) e a tarifa do dia (`precos_i`), tanto o atual quanto dos próximos 502 dias (é programado para baixar 731 dias, mas o site disponibiliza apenas 502).

O código baixa essas variáveis e armazena em um dataframe (`banco_precos_i`) que vai compor o dataframe da página(`banco_precos`) e posteriormente o dataframe do dia (`banco_precos_dia`). Ao final os dados de todos os dias irão compor um único dataframe (`banco_precos_final`).

Quando chega no dia 10/09/2020, na [página 6](https://www.booking.com/searchresults.pt-br.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaCCIAQGYAS24ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQuIAgGoAgO4AvPJg_UFwAIB&sid=7012276e733450114e779126fd1d96bf&tmpl=searchresults&checkin_month=9&checkin_monthday=10&checkin_year=2020&checkout_month=9&checkout_monthday=11&checkout_year=2020&class_interval=1&dest_id=-656888&dest_type=city&dtdisc=0&from_sf=1&group_adults=2&group_children=0&inac=0&index_postcard=0&label_click=undef&nflt=ht_id%3D204%3Bht_id%3D216%3Bht_id%3D203%3Bht_id%3D206%3B&no_rooms=1&percent_htype_hotel=1&postcard=0&raw_dest_type=city&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&shw_aparth=1&slp_r_match=0&src=index&srpvid=c8ad05539d6400f3&ss=Natal&ss_all=0&ssb=empty&sshis=0&ssne=Natal&ssne_untouched=Natal&top_ufis=1&rows=25&offset=125) , e durante alguns dias de setembro, o número linhas de `quarto_i` é diferente de `nomes_i` e `precos_i`, que tem sempre o mesmo tamanho, o que impossibilita de gerar o dataframe *banco_precos_i* e consequentemente os demais.

Erro informado:

```
Error in data.frame(nomes_i, quarto_i, precos_i, stringsAsFactors = F) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 18, 17].
```

Falta algum valor que não estou conseguindo capturar e nem inserir a informação NA no lugar dessa única informação faltante.

Como solução estou colocando durante o mês de setembro todos os dados de `quarto_i` para baixar como NA, mas essa informação é muito importante para minha análise e gostaria de tentar outra solução.

Tentei as duas sugestões que constam [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901532/inputting-na-where-there-are-missing-values-when-scraping-with-rvest), para baixar apenas o dado faltante, mas não funcionou. Alguém tem outra sugestão?

PS.: estou informando apenas as partes do código que estão relacionados ao problema:

```
library(lubridate) 
library(rvest) 
library(devtools)
library(tidyverse) 
library(rlang) 
library(curl)

inicio <- today()
dias <- 0
banco_precos_dia <- c()
banco_precos_final <- c()

for (i in 0:731) {

# data do checkin 
  diacheckin <-  as.Date("2020-09-10")+ddays(i) #estou colocando o as.Date aqui para o código já começar a baixar de onde dá erro, geralmente a variável que vai aqui é inicio
  diain <- as.numeric(day(diacheckin))
  mesin <- as.numeric(month(diacheckin))
  anoin <- as.numeric(year(diacheckin))

# data do check out
  diacheckout <- diacheckin+ddays(1)
  diaout <- as.numeric(day(diacheckout))
  mesout <- as.numeric(month(diacheckout))
  anoout <- as.numeric(year(diacheckout))

qtd <- 250 #existe uma programação para calcular exatamente a quantidade aqui, mas ela não é relevante para este problema

  banco_precos <- c()
  banco_precos_i <- c()

  for(j in seq(0,qtd,25)){
    url_number <- j

    #buscando a pagina

    url <- curl(paste0('https://www.booking.com/searchresults.pt-br.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaCCIAQGYAS24ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQuIAgGoAgO4AvCp5vIFwAIB&sid=b0ea1003a80543236a20e94559c4ed28&tmpl=searchresults&checkin_month=',mesin,'&checkin_monthday=',diain,'&checkin_year=',anoin,'&checkout_month=',mesout,'&checkout_monthday=',diaout,'&checkout_year=',anoout,'&city=-656888&class_interval=1&dest_id=-656888&dest_type=city&dtdisc=0&from_sf=1&group_adults=2&group_children=0&inac=0&index_postcard=0&label_click=undef&nflt=ht_id%3D203%3Bht_id%3D204%3Bht_id%3D206%3Bht_id%3D216%3B&no_rooms=1&postcard=0&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&shw_aparth=1&slp_r_match=0&src=searchresults&src_elem=sb&srpvid=3de2a5cdcd850113&ss=Natal&ss_all=0&ssb=empty&sshis=0&ssne=Natal&ssne_untouched=Natal&top_ufis=1&rows=25&offset=',url_number), "rb")

    #lendo a pagina
    page <- read_html(url)

 #nome dos hoteis
   nomes_i <-page %>%
      html_nodes(".sr-hotel__name") %>%
      html_text()%>%
      {if(length(.) == 0) NA else .}

    #nome do quarto
    quarto_i <- page%>%
     html_nodes(".room_link strong ,  .sold_out_property") %>%
     html_text()%>%
      {if(length(.) == 0) NA else .}

#*quando chega no dia 10/09 e o erro ocorre, eu paro o código, troco o código acima por quarto_i<- NA, espero baixar o mês de setembro e volto a baixar outubro em diante com o código acima - tudo manualmente*

   #precos
    precos_i <- page %>%
      html_nodes(".bui-price-display__value , .sold_out_property ") %>%
      html_text()%>%
      {if(length(.) == 0) NA else .}

    #construindo o banco de dados de cada página
    banco_precos_i <- data.frame(nomes_i, quarto_i, precos_i, stringsAsFactors = F)

    #alimentando o banco de dados de um dia
    banco_precos <- rbind(banco_precos ,banco_precos_i)

    #banco de preço dia     
    banco_precos_dia <- cbind(inicio,banco_precos,diacheckin)

    #suspender execucao no R por 3 seg
    Sys.sleep(3)
}
banco_precos_final <- rbind(banco_precos_final, banco_precos_dia)
}
}
```

Comment: Como alguém conseguiu rodar esse código, o erro pode ter relação com a resposta recebida do servidor pelo R. As vezes você pode tentar verificar que recebeu a resposta adequada do servidor (o pacote `httr` pode ajudar).

Comment: A mensagem de erro, contudo, sugere algumas das informações que você pegou veio incompleta na hora de formar o `banco_precos_i`. Por isso diz que enquanto uma tem 18 elementos, outra tem 17. Nesse caso poderia introduzir uma verificação antes de criar o `banco_precos_i` e pensar numa estratégia para igualar o tamanho dos vetores.

Comment: Olá @TomásBarcellos, sim, é isso que estou tentando resolver. Você conseguiu rodar 
o código? Estou utilizando o pacote `rvest` para a raspagem, você sugere alguma função do `httr` que possa me ajudar ? Não vi funções nesse pacote que diferem do rvest para a raspagem. Conforme expliquei ao @Tusca, ao explorar as orientações dele descobri que na página 6 há um hotel em específico (Hostel Margo) que os valores vem diferentes. Não há a informação do quarto em `.roomlink strong` para esse hotel e há dois quartos em `.roomlink`, você tem alguma sugestão para solucionar isso?

Comment: Uma solução seria você "obrigar" o código a unir as informações do quarto em um unico elemento. Ex: `paste(texto_quartos, collapse = " ")`. Depois de feita a raspagem você poderia ou pensar em como tratar

Comment: Outra possibilidade seria criar uma variavel `quarto2` na tabela, que fica quase sempre vazia, mas que nesses casos seria preenchidas. Ou ainda somar o tamanho de todos os quartos e só guardar essa informação.

Comment: Ou ainda quardar a informação de quantos quartos tem, etc, etc... Mas só você poderá determinar a melhor estratégia para seu caso específico

Answer (score 0):

Seu código executou sem erro por aqui.
Tentei gerar um erro de propósito no vetorde quartos e mesmo assim funcionou, colocou os NA's onde não encontrou nada:

[image]

Talvez o que esteja acontecendo é um block do servidor no seu IP por gerar muitas consultas no site. Isso pode te retornar páginas html com erros.
Sugestão: quando identifica esse erro no seu código, salva a variável "page" com extensão .hmtl e da uma olhadinha no seu browser como está a página, se apresenta algo estranho nos elementos.

Comment: Olá @tusca. Tentei baixar começando a partir de 10/09 para explorar a possibilidade de ser um block do servidor, mas deu erro na página 6. Acessando exatamente essa página vi que o _Hostel Margo_, ao invés do nome do quarto aparecem dois dormitórios (e que não constam no `.room_link strong`), tentei baixar o `.roomname` ou `.room_link` ao invés do `.room_link strong`, mas continua dando o erro pois agora baixa dois nomes para esse hotel ao invés de apenas 1, você sabe como posso agrupar esses dormitórios em um só? Inclui o link da página na pergunta, pois excede os caracteres dos comentários